# Model attribute null on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple application that I've loosely based off the MVC Music store used in a tutorial on asp.net that allows a user to enter details about TV shows that they are watching so they can keep track of which episode they're up to in each show.

The main entities in my application are Show:

```
Public class Show
{
      // a few automatic properties
      public int id { get; set; }
      public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

and the Genre class

```
Public partial class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Show> Shows { get; set; }
}
```

My POST edit method in my controller was generated by VS for me:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Show show)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(show).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(show);
    }
```

When I inspect db in the debugger, I can see that the Show objects (however many are in the database at the time. I seed it with two but usually add a third via the form) all have the genres I've entered but after the Edit action returns the view, the Genre is null while all the other values are updated. Why is this?

I thought perhaps the genre field was null because I wasn't instantiating them but where would I do that? I don't want a new genre created every time a Show's genre is set. I just want a show to have a genre reference so that I can eventually allow the user to select a genre and see all the shows they're following of that genre.

EDIT: Here's my Edit View. The Details view also looks very similar.

```
@model watchedCatalogue2.Models.Show

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Genre.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Number of episodes")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NoEpisodes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NoEpisodes)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Number of episodes watched")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NoEpisodesWatched)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NoEpisodesWatched)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Watching State")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,      watchedCatalogue2.Models.Show.WatchStateItems)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Also, for good measure, db in my controller refers to my CatalogueEntities class:

```
namespace watchedCatalogue2.Models
{
    public class CatalogueEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is incomplete (`P`ublic?).  I assume you have a `GenreId` on the `Show` object.  Have you tried binding/setting that instead, and then simply saving.

Comment: @AndrewBacker, the GenreId is on the Genre object. The Show object just has a reference to the Genre object. In my edit view you should be able to see what I'm doing. I'm trying to take what the user has entered and bind it to Show.Genre.Name. 

It just doesn't seem to stick even after db.SaveChanges() which I thought would write anything new to the database. I see that the genre is null after db.dispose is called (after SaveChanges of course).

Comment: Nice update to the post.  I think it might be easier to answer now :)

Comment: As another note, I wouldn't use `EditiorFor`, but rather use `TextboxFor` and so on.  If you have a custom editor like for `DateTime` (though I tend to use jQuery for this) or a custom model then ok.

Comment: The `EditorFor` is just scaffolding and I didn't think to change it. Would you use `TextboxFor` for input validation reasons or something else?

Comment: I can never recall exactly why, except for the ability to add additional html attributes using `TextboxFor`, but we keep stumbling on corner cases that pushed us back to `TextboxFor`. Editor for is fine, but you need to write custom templates (complex), and it ended up obscuring whats happening.  Actually, now our apps all use custom helpers like `TextboxFor` to keep things simple (and they usually call `TextboxFor` (etc) internally.  `EditorFor` was nice in theory, but I can't see needing to globally replace `<input type="text">`.

Comment: One other thing, `EditorFor` is "smart" and chooses the editor/template for you. Its just one more level of (unnecessary) indirection that looses a few features.  If I want a textbox, I want to say "textboxFor" in the html.  Then we had a `DropdownFor` for dropdowns, etc, with NO need for data annotations.  Our html now tells us exactly what we will be rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I noticed many of the model classes in the examples had references to other models that were marked as virtual. I figured I had nothing to lose so I modified my Show class so `public Genre Genre { get; set; }` now reads `public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }`. Suddenly it all works. I'd appreciate if someone who knows why it works could explain it to me because all I've seen thus far have been references to lazy loading but nothing relating to my problem.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the fact that in MVC all the data is not retained/posted onto the POST method, but only those rendered as an editable element on the View and contained in the Model.

The simplest work-around will be to render it as a hidden field, as follows:

MVC 2.0 and earlier:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GenreId) %>
```

Razor:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GenreId)
```

If you use AJAX or something similar, you could also just send/pass the value as a parameter.

Also note, if you make use of the ModelState.IsValid functionality, it is possible and very probable that the Hidden fields would be rendered as null, and most probably as a problem. To remove this, which is not always advised, just add `ModelState.Remove("TheKey");`, in your case it is probably, `ModelState.Remove("GenreID");`

Comment: If I'm understanding your answer correctly, you're saying that the data won't be retained unless it is on the view (whether visible or hidden). I've updated my original question to include the view that I'm getting the data from and there is a visible field there with the GenreId so, correct me if I'm wrong, the hidden field wouldn't be needed.

Comment: I do not see a hidden field for the genre id in the view.  If you don't have a hidden field, then the browser won't re-post the GenreID to your controller.  Also, it is a good idea to not use the DB entities in the view, and create a custom model class (validation, model binding, etc).   Use the DB entities directly if you are just showing the data, but not for editing/etc.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but at the top of my view I've got "@model watchedCatalogue2.Models.Show". Is that not telling the view that my model is the Show class? Am I not then referring to the model class rather than the DB entities (which, I believe are "Shows" (plural) and "Genres")?

Also, why does the GenreID need to be in the form? I have a visible field for the Genre's name which is a property of the genre class. Does the framework need the ID field specifically for some reason relating to mapping to the database?

Comment: I have been playing around a little and by adding a hidden field for GenreID to the Edit view, the POST edit method never enters the if loop because `ModelState.IsValid` is now false. When I look at the ModelStateDictionary, it has a number of keys, one being the GenreID which is still null.

Comment: To a dd to my previous comment, the ModelState dictionary also contains the value that was entered in the form but it is not null. It's only the GenreID that's null but I have no idea what I can do about that.

Comment: Added bottom part in my answer about the ModelState.IsValid. If you are not going to ever have this field edited or validated, you can just remove the ModelState key?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following the problem right, you need to render it on the form in some way for the data to be maintained, bearing in mind the web is stateless, if the value isn't present when the form is posted, it won't be bound back on to your view model.

On your view include in the form:

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GenreId)

Or depending on what your URL is like on your Get, you could change your POST method signature to include the id.

Comment: See my comment to HowlinWulf's answer. I have rendered it on the form but the data still seems to be discarded when the db context is disposed of.

Comment: Sorry, so with the update code, you need the hiddenfor for the Id which you have but what I suggested above should be:  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Genre.GenreId)  Just a note, for convention you'd usually call the primary key of each table 'Id' without the entity name.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. It reads nicer as well.

I've been playing around with that for a few hours now. It hasn't resolved the problem, the Genre name is still not being saved to the database, but it has changed it. The ModelState is now invalid which prevents the edit action from entering the if loop that saves changes to the database but from what I can tell, it is invalid because the Genre is null so I'm left with a very similar problem.